# Tabularx printing regex incorrectly

Tags: tables, verbatim, tabularx

When printing regex in a `tabularx` environment, spaces get inserted after each character class. Is there any way to fix this?

**MWE:**

```
\usepackage{tabularx}

Outside table: \verb~/\d+/~

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l}
Inside table: \verb~/\d+/~ \\
\end{tabularx}
```

[image: Outside table: /\d+/ Inside table: /\d +/]

Comment: yes that's what it says in the `tabularx` manual.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle where in the manual?

Comment: Page 2, footnote

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. Is there another way to print regex?

Comment: you could use  `\texttt{/\string\d+/}`

Comment: @egreg I can't imagine what you are referring to!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle so there's no way of printing raw regex: I need to escape it?

Comment: In general you can not use \verb in the argument of another command, and the body of tabularx (like ams alignments or environments defined with environ package) are really the argument to a command, so that they can be evaluated multiple times for trial table settings. `tabularx` fakes verb with `\meaning` which works for simple cases, b ut information about whether or not a space was after the `\d` is simply not there by the time the command is executed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this can be a real solution to your problem, but, here is a try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\setbox0=\hbox{\verb~/\d+/~}
Outside table: \verb~/\d+/~

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l}
Inside table:  \usebox{0} \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`tabularx` only approximately implements `\verb`, but here you probably only need `\texttt` and not `\verb`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}

Outside table: \verb~/\d+/~

Outside table: \texttt{/\string\d+/}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X@{}}
Inside table:  \texttt{/\string\d+/} \\
\end{tabularx}


\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```